# Code is OK in DAO but gives run-time error '3021' in ADO

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado, dao

This occurs after replacing DAO with ADO in a VB6 project that uses an Access 97 database.

It occurs on the line marked 'Error Here in the following snippet:

```
If rset.BOF <> True Or rset.EOF <> True Then
  rset.MoveLast 
  Do While rset.BOF <> True
     rset.Delete
     If rset.BOF <> True Or rset.EOF <> True Then  
         rset.MoveLast    'Error Here
     End If
   Loop
End If
```

Run-time error '3021' gves this explanation :

> "Either EOF or BOF is True, or the
>   current record has been deleted.
>   requested operation requires a current
>   record."

It appears that after the last record in the recordset is deleted  BOF +/- EOF is still false in the ADO version of the code while both are true in the DAO version.
If I alter the code like this it works

**EDIT : the following code does NOT work. When I tried this 'solution' all the records
were already deleted from the table, therefore the entire block was bypassed and so no error was thrown. Sorry for the bad information.**

```
If rset.BOF <> True Or rset.EOF <> True Then
      rset.MoveLast 
      Do While rset.BOF <> True
         rset.Delete
         If rset.BOF <> True Or rset.EOF <> True Then 
         End If
         If rset.BOF <> True Or rset.EOF <> True Then  
             rset.MoveLast    
         End If
       Loop
End If
```

Can someone explain this? (and ideally offer a solution that does not involve changing code !)

**FURTHER EDIT : As far as I can tell having tried lots of ways, the BOF and EOF are useless in ADO for testing for an empty recordset after a delete. This is because you need to use one of the move methods to update the BOF/EOF and if the recordset is empty you'll get an error. On the recordset I used, the RecordCount property was updated after a delete. Although I am not going to use it, this code *did* work :**

```
If rset.BOF <> True Or rset.EOF <> True Then
   Do While rset.RecordCount > 0
      rset.MoveLast
      rset.Delete
   Loop
End If
```

**Edit ( 1 month later)
So after rewriting a whole pile of code I came across a loop containing a delete that didn't give an error. The only difference was that this loop was deleting the first record in the recordset each time rather than the last and therefore after each delete it executed
a MOVEFIRST rather than a MOVELAST.
So I whittled the code down as much as possible and the following snippet works fine on both Postgresql and Access, the 2 databases I tried it on, from VB6 using ADO.**

```
Do While rset.EOF <> True
     rset.Delete
     rset.MoveFirst
Loop
```

**After the deletion of the final record EOF and BOF still remain false but you won't get an error calling the MOVEFIRST method. Calling MOVEFIRST now sets both EOF and BOF to true and the loop is exited.
By contrast, if the MOVEFIRST method is replaced with a MOVELAST then the (3021) error occurs on both databases.
In his answer rskar quoted this from MSDN**

> Use the MoveNext method to move the
>   current record position one record
>   forward (toward the bottom of the
>   Recordset). If the last record is the
>   current record and you call the
>   MoveNext method, ADO sets the current
>   record to the position after the last
>   record in the Recordset (EOF is True).
>   An attempt to move forward when the
>   EOF property is already True generates
>   an error.

**They mention MOVENEXT causing an error and I suppose since MOVELAST is movement in the same direction this explains why it also causes an error. 
I just wish I hadn't assumed that all the move methods would result in similar problems**

Comment: Why in the world are you doing deletions by walking a recordset, instead of by issuing a SQL DELETE statement?

Comment: maybe because he thinks he is free to use the delete method of the recordset object?

Comment: @Phillippe Exactly! It did its job well for many years too until I have tried to move from DAO to ADO.

Comment: @David At the time it was the only way I knew how to do it. The way you suggest is how I would do it now

Comment: @Philippe: the .Delete method *does* work. You just have to know how to use the other properties of the Recordset object appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675787(v=vs.85).aspx:

> If you delete the last remaining
>   record in the Recordset object, the
>   BOF and EOF properties may remain
>   False until you attempt to reposition
>   the current record.

Since ADO isn't DAO, differences in behavior shouldn't be too surprising. It would seem that a call to MoveLast may trigger an update to BOF/EOF. I think you may be forced into coding changes.

For kicks and giggles, give this a try (don't know if it'll work):

```
rset.Delete 
rset.MoveNext
If rset.BOF <> True Or rset.EOF <> True Then                 
    rset.MoveLast               
End If
```

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677527(v=vs.85).aspx:

> Use the MoveNext method to move the
>   current record position one record
>   forward (toward the bottom of the
>   Recordset). If the last record is the
>   current record and you call the
>   MoveNext method, ADO sets the current
>   record to the position after the last
>   record in the Recordset (EOF is True).
>   An attempt to move forward when the
>   EOF property is already True generates
>   an error.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Unfortunately, rset.movenext does not seem to work, the same error is thrown. Neither, actually, does the solution I thought I had. I edited the question to reflect that. I think some rewriting along the lines that David-W-Fenton suggests in his comment under the question will be necessary.

Comment: @jjb - David's answer is the best way go. Good luck!

Comment: I made a small discovery related to this question which might be of interest to you and edited the question accordingly